# What is a systematic process for choosing a mobile game engine?

Tags: methodology

I am looking for a systematic process or methodology for choosing a mobile game engine for a mobile game project.

Intuition tells me that it should be similar in principle to choosing any off-the-shelf product (requirements, evaluation, short-list, trial, etc).

Any suggested processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention it is `similar in principle to choosing any off-the-shelf product (requirements, evaluation, short-list, trial, etc)`.

As to `[a]ny links or perhaps suggested processes?`:

For software in general [How to Choose Business Software](http://www.wikihow.com/Choose-Business-Software) and [How to Choose Software](http://www.procad.com/blog/2012/01/29/how-to-choose-software/), both offer different styles. The first is a common step-by-step 10 item list with some additional Tips, the second is one man's opinion in 3 paragraphs followed by 2 marketing his own.  The second, however, is more closely related to game development because it focuses on productivity exclusively.

As for development specific there is the [15 Most Important Considerations when Choosing a Web Development Framework](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/15-most-important-considerations-when-choosing-a-web-development-framework/) and [Choosing the Right Java Web Development Framework](http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2010/choosing-the-right-java-web-development-framework/).  The first here applies to any framework (except for the question of which JavaScript library is included), which is essentially what a game engine is.  The second provides more of a magazine Top 10 ranking process.

Finally, I just found [How to Choose a Mobile Game Engine](http://mobilegameengines.com/how_to_choose_a_mobile_game_engine), but it is not yet published.

Comment: Great links, I appreciate the research.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer when you are able to.